# If two homeomorphisms $f,g:X\to Y$ are homotopic, then their inverses are also homotopic.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

This is an exercise from *Fundamental Groups & Covering Spaces* by Lima:

**If two homeomorphisms $f,g:X\to Y$ are homotopic, then their inverses are also homotopic.**

Below is my thought for a solution, but I am not sure about it.

Since $f\simeq g$ then there exists a continuous map $H:X\times I\to Y$ such that $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x)$. Moreover, this defines a family of maps $H_t:X\to Y$ where $H_t (x)=H(x,t)$ for all $x\in X$.

To define a homotopy $G:Y\times I\to X$ from $f^{-1}$ to $g^{-1}$, I think it should be something similar to the following: $$G(y,t)=H_t^{-1}(y),$$
for each $y\in Y$, and where $H_t^{-1}$ is the inverse of $H_t$.

Clearly then $G(y,0)=H_0^{-1}(y)=f^{-1}(y)$ and $G(y,1)=H_1^{-1}(y)=g^{-1}(y)$.

What I am not sure about is if each $H_t$ for $0<t<1$ is actually invertible. Since $f$ and $g$ are homeomorphisms, then of course they are invertible, but what about each transitory map in the homotopy?

Comment: We only know $H_t^{-1}$ exists and is continuous for $t=0,1.$ So using $H_t^{-1}$ isn't going to work.

Comment: Hint: It is enough to assume $X=Y$ and $g$ is the identity homeomorphism (why?)

Comment: For example, if $X=Y=\mathbb R$ and $f(x)=-x, g(x)=x,$ we can find a homotopy between then, but not all of the $H_t$ will be invertible.

Comment: Okay, so my suspicion about that was correct. Thanks for the hint. I'll think about it some time more.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume $f,g:X\rightarrow Y$ are homeomorphisms and are homotopic.

Let $H:X\times I\rightarrow Y$ be a homotopy from $f$ to $g$.

We aim to show that $f^{-1},g^{-1}:Y\rightarrow X$ are homotopic.

The map $G:Y\times I\rightarrow X$, $G(y,t)=f^{-1}(H(g^{-1}(y),1-t)))$ is the desired homotopy

Comment: This is the homotopy you get if you trace through the argument: if $f \sim g$, then $f^{-1} \circ f \circ g^{-1} \sim f^{-1} \circ g \circ g^{-1}$, so $g^{-1} \sim f^{-1}$; and now use symmetry to get $f^{-1} \sim g^{-1}$.